# Mid-range Smarthphone

Tags: android

I'm currently looking for a new phone as my Nexus 5X passed away recently. My boss was so kind to give be a bonus in the form that the company will buy me a new phone in the 300€ to 350€ range.

What I would like is:

- At least Full HD
- USB C (possibly w/ USB 3.0)
- No notch
- Headphone Jack
- 4 GB of ram or more
- 4G+ (or at least 4G)
- 5" to 5.8" screen size possibly
- CPU at least as powerful as the Nexus 5X
- Camera is not super important but at least as good as the Nexus 5X
- 32GB internal storage
- A whole day of battery
- Fingerprint reader

Nice to have:

- Fingerprint reader preferably on the back
- NFC
- Dual SIM and microSD (absolutely not necessary)
- 16:9 aspect ratio (I dislike 18:9 but I can live with it I guess..)
- Lineage OS support

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the [Mate 9 Pro](https://www.gsmarena.com/huawei_mate_9_pro-8396.php) fits (lamost) all your desires:

- At least Full HD: **check (QHD)**
- USB C (possibly w/ USB 3.0): **half check (USB C but 2.0)**
- No notch: **check**
- Headphone Jack: **check**
- 4 GB of ram or more: **check (4 or 6GB)**
- 4G+ (or at least 4G): **check (4G+)**
- 5" to 5.8" screen size possibly: **check (5.5")**
- CPU at least as powerful as the Nexus 5X: **check (octa core Kirin 960)**
- Camera is not super important but at least as good as the Nexus 5X: **check**
- 32GB internal storage: **check 64 or 128GB**
- A whole day of battery: **check (4000mAh)**
- NFC: **check**
- Dual SIM and microSD (absolutely not necessary): **half check (dual sim, no µSD, but 64/128GB internal huh)**
- 16:9 aspect ratio (I dislike 18:9 but I can live with it I guess..): **check**
- IR: **check**
- Lineage OS support: **check**

The price depends on your country, I found quite easily 350/360€ models in France. (maybe good deals during Black Friday ?)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! It really seems to check almost all the boxes. Though it is too expensive (568,33€ on amazon.it) and I can't wait until black Friday. Where did you find those prices? Also, something I forgot to mention, and I will edit the question accordingly, is that I really would prefer it if the fingerprint reader was on the back. If this phone was cheaper I would go for it!

Comment: @Mattia_98 alright so few proposals: [Nokia 6.1](https://www.gsmarena.com/nokia_6_1-8972.php), [Nokia 8](https://www.gsmarena.com/nokia_8-8522.php), [Huawai 9](https://www.gsmarena.com/huawei_honor_9-8704.php) and [Samsung A8 2018](https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_a8_(2018)-8886.php) though the Nokia have a locked bootloader (so no Lineage) and the A8 has 18.5:9 ratio display.

Answer (score 1):

My Recommendation : **Xiaomi Mi A2**

- USB C
- Snapdragon 660
- No Notch
- 6" Display [LCD]
- 3000 mAh Battery
- Android One [Currently in Android Pie] w/ Custom Rom Support
- 4+64GB 6+64GB Configuration
- IR Blaster

Only Downside is No Expandable Storage.

For More Info : https://www.gsmarena.com/xiaomi_mi_a2_(mi_6x)-9140.php